# Updating the view across two different controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a simple mobile messaging application using the ionic Framework. There are two views, one for Messages and one for Requests. When a request is accepted, the user should be removed from the Request view (and list of request) and moved to the Messages view (and pushed to the list of messages).

There are two controllers, RequestCtrl and MessageCtrl. When the request is accepted in the view, RequestCtrl removes the user from the list of requests, and adds the user to the list of messages in the MessageCtrl. So far, this has been done by creating an Angular service:

```
app.factory('$chats', ['$localstorage', '$http', '$rootScope',
function($localstorage, $http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        refresh: function() {
            var messages = [];
            var user = $localstorage.getObject('user');
            console.log("message before user");
            console.log(user);
            for (var i = 0; i < user.interactions.length; i++) {
                if (user.interactions[i].isConnected == "connected") {
                    var friend = user.interactions[i].user_id;
                    $http.get('/get_profile?id=' + friend).then(function(resp) {
                        messages.push({
                            "_id": resp.data._id,
                            "profileImg": resp.data.profileImg,
                            "firstName": resp.data.firstName,
                            "lastName": resp.data.lastName,
                            "lastMessage": "This is placeholder text"
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
            // $rootScope.$broadcast("chatsUpdated");
            return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the lists are updated, the view does not update. I've tried pushing out an event using $emit and $broadcast when the service is called, and catching it with $on in the MessageCtrl but it doesn't seem to update.

I'm pretty new to Angular, so I may be missing something but I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the correct direction!

Comment: can you please post here also the `MessageCtrl ` code too.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit begin:**

Assuming that your have in your controller `$scope.messages = $chats.refresh()`...

**Edit end:**

Your Problem may be that you create and return a new Array with `var messages = []`. Angular still watches the previously generated Array and will never get aware of the changes.

Just pass the original array `refresh(messages)` and empty the array with `messages.length = 0`. That will keep the original array that you attached to the scope.

Comment: Your answer is very ambiguous. You don't see any watchers in the presented code, thus your answer should be an answer and not a supposition. Ask for details and when you are sure, post the answer.

Comment: I just edited the code to include an assumption. However: If angular is watching the messages array the given code must fail.

Comment: Now is better. Agree, but we need to see the MessageCtrl to find what is the issue.